# How to build a Url?

Tags: c#, .net

Are there any helper classes available in .NET to allow me to build a Url?

For example, if a user enters a string:

```
stackoverflow.com
```

and i try to pass that to an `HttpWebRequest`:

```
WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
```

It will fail, because it is not a valid url (it has no prefix).

What i want is to be able to parse the partial url the user entered:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
```

and then fix the missing pieces:

```
if (uri.Port == 0)
   uri.Port = 3333;
if (uri.Scheme == "")
   uri.Scheme = "https";
```

Does .NET have any classes that can be used to parse and manipulate Uri's?

## The UriBuilder class can't do the job

The value that the user entered (e.g. `stackoverflow.com:3333`) is valid; i just need a class to pick it apart. i *tried* using the `UriBuilder` class:

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("stackoverflow.com:3333");
```

unfortunately, the UriBuilder class is unable to handle URIs:

- uriBuilder.Path = `3333`
- uriBuilder.Port = `-1`
- uriBuidler.Scheme = `stackoverflow.com`

So i need a class that can understand `host:port`, which especially becomes important when [it's not particularly `http`, but could be](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification).

## Bonus Chatter

Console application.

## From the other question

Some examples of URL's that require parsing:

- `server:8088`
- `server:8088/func1`
- `server:8088/func1/SubFunc1`
- `http://server`
- `http://server/func1`
- `http://server/func/SubFunc1`
- `http://server:8088`
- `http://server:8088/func1`
- `http://server:8088/func1/SubFunc1`
- `magnet://server`
- `magnet://server/func1`
- `magnet://server/func/SubFunc1`
- `magnet://server:8088`
- `magnet://server:8088/func1`
- `magnet://server:8088/func1/SubFunc1`
- `http://[2001:db8::1]`
- `http://[2001:db8::1]:80`

The format of a Url is:

```
  foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \_________/ \__/\_________/\__________/ \__/
   |         |        |     |           |        |
scheme      host    port   path       query   fragment
```

### Bonus Chatter

Just to point out again that **UriBuilder** does not work:

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/s66kdZ

Comment: It looks like `UriBuilder` handles this correctly - `stackoverflow.com:3333` is a URI with scheme `stackoverflow.com` and path `3333`. If you want something to parse it differently you'll have to specify how you want the behaviour to differ. You might just be able to assume an unknown scheme is a hostname, or write your own [UriParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uriparser?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The problem is that the scheme is not `stackoverflow.com`. Just ask Lynx, Netscape Navigator, Internet Explorer, FireFox, Chrome, Edge, and the [living standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-parsing). They all realize that `stackoverflow.com` is the host. I want that Uri parser that every practical real-world parser understands. If you're suggesting i write my own, that's fine - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164298) where i ask how to do it. Ideally the class already exists in the FCL.

Comment: Your "format of a URL" contradicts the specification.  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.1 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3   Note also in 4.2 "A path segment that contains a colon character (e.g., "this:that")
   cannot be used as the first segment of a relative-path reference, as
   it would be mistaken for a scheme name."

Comment: @BenVoigt I know it violates the spec. That is why i am looking for code that can build a URL entered by a user. User's don't care about the RFC, and neither do i.

Comment: @IanBoyd: For your particular examples you can use `new UriBuilder(userInput.Contains("://")? userInput: $"defaultscheme:{userInput}")`.  It will, however, make a mess of `mailto:` URIs

Comment: @BenVoigt And also websocket URIs.

Comment: @IanBoyd: Both `ws` and `wss` schemes use an authority introduced by `//`, so that code snippet should work fine with them.

Answer (score 85):

If you need to ensure that some string coming as user input is valid url you could use the [`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Uri uri;
string someUrl = ...
if (!Uri.TryCreate(someUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    // the someUrl string did not contain a valid url 
    // inform your users about that
}
else
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    // ... safely proceed with executing the request
}
```

Now if on the other hand you want to be building urls in .NET there's the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class specifically designed for that purpose. Let's take an example. Suppose you wanted to build the following url: `http://example.com/path?foo=bar&baz=bazinga#some_fragment` where the `bar` and `bazinga` values are coming from the user:

```
string foo = ... coming from user input
string baz = ... coming from user input

var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://example.com/path");
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
parameters["foo"] = foo;
parameters["baz"] = baz;
uriBuilder.Query = parameters.ToString();
uriBuilder.Fragment = "some_fragment";

Uri finalUrl = uriBuilder.Uri;
var request = WebRequest.Create(finalUrl);
... safely proceed with executing the request
```

Comment: `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` is a sneaky way to get an `HttpValueCollection` which is internal (that's why its `.ToString()` works like that). Not sure it's a good idea to use internal framework classes and rely on their undocumented behavior. Credit for this insight goes to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91783/constructing-a-query-string-using-stringbuilder#comment166606_91795

Comment: @JesseHufstetler - I think it is safe to use since the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=netframework-4.8) about it doesn't mention any warnings, and has examples of usage.

Comment: Note that UriBuilder chokes on [`stackoverflow.com:3389`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s66kdZ)

Answer (score 20):

You can use the [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class.

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(url);
builder.Port = 3333
builder.Scheme = "https";

var result = builder.Uri;
```

Comment: It chokes on `stackoverflow.com:3389`

Answer (score 8):

To be valid a URI needs to have the scheme component. "server:8088" is not a valid URI. "http://server:8088" is. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Comment: And yet your Chrome browser knows what i mean when you type in `stackoverflow.com:80`. What .NET class is able to parse URIs.

Comment: Actually, server:8080 is a perfectly valid URI, though probably nobody is going to understand what you mean with the server scheme.

Comment: always thought scheme would be `server://` not `server:port` but it is interesting to ponder basic rules of understanding

Comment: @IanBoyd: Some browsers just know what the most common typo's are and adjust themselves to it ;-)

Comment: @Ian: Chrome just detects the parsing failure and tries again, this time with `"https://" + userinput`  That's not a URL manipulation, it's a string manipulation.