# Can not create valid URL

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a valid URL:

```
private string Urlpath { get; set; }
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Urlpath);

    private void Button_URL(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new MyDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Refreshing a URL requires you to select a folder.");
            string Urlpath = dialog.ResponseText;
            Status_HTML.Content = "Selected:" + "\n" + Urlpath + "\n" + "Save and/or edit any file in your folder to get started!";
        }
    }
```

Urlpath is a string value from an input box like http://localhost/laravel/project/public/ but it says that its not a valid url.
Actually it says **System.ArgumentNullException: Argument 'url' cannot be null.** because it probably only accept valid Urls but there's a string value. How can I turn this string into a URL?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164298/how-to-build-a-url)

Comment: Where have you assigned value to UrlPath variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned any value to the `UrlPath` property, Assign the required URL to `UrlPath` property and then use it to pass to the method.

```
Urlpath = "http://localhost/laravel/project/public/";
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Urlpath);
```

EDIT
You need to call Navigate after you have assigned `UrlPath` property from the `dialog.ResponseText`
    private string Urlpath { get; set; }

```
    private void Button_URL(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new MyDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Refreshing a URL requires you to select a folder.");
            string Urlpath = dialog.ResponseText;
            Status_HTML.Content = "Selected:" + "\n" + Urlpath + "\n" + "Save and/or edit any file in your folder to get started!";
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Urlpath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works but whenever I ask for input and the input would be http://localhost/laravel/project/public/ - it does not recognise it as a url

Comment: From where are you taking input, please paste the complete code of yours, also there need to be protocol i.e http or https to make a valid URL

Comment: I have edited my code, it shows the url in html_content but in a method it says that the get returned null

Comment: Can't I use it in another method? because I want to call the go to url in a file changed method

Comment: You can always call the method once the UrlPath is assigned the proper value

Comment: Looks like I had to remove string from Urlpath