# Correct way of manipulating the url coming from App.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, app-config

I have a URL ("http://localhost:2477/") on which I do get and post request. I have stored this URL in the app.config file of my project.

In the code, depending on the function, I add the string "getValue?id={0}" or "postValue" to this URL. But I later ran into an issue when I changed the URL to "http://localhost:2477" (no forward slash in the end) in the app.config.

Took me some embarrassing amount of time to figure out this issue, which made me wonder if there is a good way to handle this case.

Irrespective of the case when there is a forward slash or not in the URL, I want my code to change it to a proper URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `Path.Combine(string, string)`. This method will conform a valid path and should add the `/` if needed.

**edit** 
I realized my answer does not work for URL, just for file paths.

What you’re looking for is `Uri` constructor instead.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");

Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class you can modify your URL more elegantly. You can access the Host, Port, Query, etc. with ease. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713542/elegant-way-parsing-url).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the UriBuilder, it's far more flexible as the Uri Constructor.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20164328/10574963