# Sending URL Link to Email ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url.action

I'm trying to generate a confirmation link to be sent to the email. The email was sent and received but the link is just not there.
heres the code

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail(Otp request)
        {

            randomcode = CreateRandomToken();
            var confirmationLink = Url.Action("confirmotp", "Authentication", new {randomcode}, Request.Scheme);
            var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(_config.GetSection("EmailUsername").Value));
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(request.EmailAddress));
            email.Subject = "Confirmation Link For" + (request.EmailAddress);
            email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
            {
                Text = "Hello " + request.EmailAddress + ", click on the link: " + confirmationLink
            }
            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect(_config.GetSection("EmailHost").Value, 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            smtp.Authenticate(_config.GetSection("EmailUsername").Value, _config.GetSection("EmailPassword").Value);
            smtp.Send(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
            return Ok();
        }
```

and this is the email I received :

*Hello xxx@gmail.com, click on the link:*

the link is just not being read. appreciate any help i can get thank you.

Comment: What is the value of confirmationLink  when you inspect it in the debugger?

Comment: its not returning anything. just null.

Comment: so I think you can hard code a string as the url to be be value of variable `confirmationLink ` then test again. If it worked,  then try to troubleshoot why `Url.Action` didn't return correct value. By the way, can [this] help you?(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#overloads)

Comment: @TinyWang yes i did the hard code one and it worked. still not sure why url.action didnt return any value and thank you for the link, I have looked into, gonna try with those methods. thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply, hard code string can work, then we only need to troubleshoot Url.Action ...

Answer (score -1):

Please try this to create the URL:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
```

More details can be found in [How to build a Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164298/how-to-build-a-url)

Comment: thank you but  its not working

Comment: Is it throwing some error, can you debug this step by step and check. And check the email body content. Is this contains the generated link?